Chinese online novel
After one night stand, female lead leaves the country. She returns with her genius son. Male lead attends an auction with a female partner and bids for an item. Female lead asks her son to bid it for her and the son wins the bid. Male lead recognises his son. It’s a pretty good story. The female lead has few high end brothers supporting her. Female lead is escaping from a very notorious villain who needs her blood to cure himself. Female lead brothers even change her whole blood in her body.
It’s a completed novel with a happy ending. During the climax Villian kidnaps female lead and hides her in his private island for transfusion of her blood into his body. Only one can survive, either the Villian or female lead. At the end Villian sacrifices himself and transfuses his blood to the female lead. In return he asks her son to be the head of his clan(some kind of underworld mafia.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Can you be more specific about when you read this?  Do you remember what site?  When you say it's Chinese, was the text itself in Chinese or did you read a translation?

Hi, I read it during corona lockdown time. It’s a Chinese novel translated into English. I’m not sure where I have read it. Think in l novelhall or novel updates

It’s a completed novel with a happy ending. During the climax Villian kidnaps female lead and hides her in his private island for transfusion of her blood into his body. Only one can survive, either the Villian or female lead. At the end Villian sacrifices himself and transfuses his blood to the female lead. In return he asks her son to be the head of his clan(some kind of underworld mafia).

What exactly are the sci-fi/fantasy elements? If there are none, this should have been asked on Literature SE.
